# Google Protocol Buffers v3 default values workaround

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I know that Google removed the ability to add default values like [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#optional) from version 3 of their Protocol Buffers specification, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a workaround to recreate this feature.

I'm working on a python web application and the best I have been able to do so far is split my `.proto` definition into 2 files:

1. A main file that conforms completely with version 3 (`syntax="proto3"`)
2. A secondary file that I import into the main file, but is declared as using version 2 of the protocol buffers specification (`syntax="proto2"`)

This seems like a bit of a hack, and I was wondering if anyone had figured out a more inventive way to recreate default values in version 3.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, the best strategy here may be to keep using proto2. Given proto2's wide use inside of Google, it is unlikely to go away any time soon.

Comment: You could use custom options in the .proto file, if the library you use supports them.